# Problem with Wordpress Comment

Tags: comments

Im sorry about my english.

I have made more than 5 comments on post pages. I have publish all the comments. But there are no comments that appear on the post page.

This is my **Comments.php** content:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

// Do not delete these lines
    if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

    if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
        <p class="nocomments">This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>
    <?php
        return;
    }
?>

<!-- You can start editing here. -->

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h3 id="comments"><?php comments_number('No Responses', 'One Response', '% Responses' );?> to &#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;</h3>

    <ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=58'); ?>
    </ol>

    <div class="navigation_comments">
        <div class="navigation_comments_alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
        <div class="navigation_comments_alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
    </div>

 <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

     <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
        <!-- If comments are closed. -->
        <p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php comment_form(); ?>

<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<div id="respond">
<h3><?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Reply', 'Leave a Reply to %s' ); ?></h3>

<div class="cancel-comment-reply">
    <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
</div>

<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
<p>You must be <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
<?php else : ?>

<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>

<?php else : ?>

<p><input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author); ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
<label for="author"><small>Name <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label></p>

<p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_email); ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
<label for="email"><small>Mail (will not be published) <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label></p>

<p><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_url); ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" />
<label for="url"><small>Website</small></label></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<!--<p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> You can use these tags: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p>-->

<p><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="58" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>

<p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment" />
<?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
</p>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

</form>

<?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
</div>

<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

In my **single.php**, I load the comment using this code: `<?php comment_form(); ?>`

Why i using ( `<?php comment_form(); ?>` ) this code, because "[Theme Check](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/)" required that.

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: hi, can you see the comments in the backend? if so what status do they have (approved/unapproved/spam) ?

Comment: Dear Birgire, I have approved all comments in my backend.

Print screen >> http://i.imgur.com/MP2jKAw.jpg

Comment: oh I know, i must using this code `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in my single.php page. Now the comments appear on the post page but i have two form comments. Print screen: http://i.imgur.com/UoeAODn.jpg

Comment: ok, my next question was about comments_template ;-) You have an extra form in your code (the input fields).

Comment: OMG, i forget i have extra form. Thank you so much Birgie, you help me solved my problem.

Comment: Dear Birgire, you have help me, i want mark your answer as accepted, but how? i dont see any mark.

Comment: thanks @v123shine, I added an answer with our progress ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here is how we solved it together ;-)

We checked the following:

- the comments are visible in the backend.
- the comment status is `approved` for all the comments.
- we need to use `comments_template()` in the template file `single.php`.
- remove the extra form (the input fields), since `comment_form()` is used.

It's informative to view the the TwentyTwelve theme files `single.php` and `comments.php` to compare.